# Jq Grid Edit creating non editable controls

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Am using JQ grid.

My Jq grid will come inside JQ dialog.

When i click on edit pop up is comming but the control are non editable.

Java Script for JQ Grid:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.viewIcon').click(function () {

            $(function () {
                $("#jqtable").dialog({
                    title: "Admin Console",
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    width: 'auto',
                    appendTo: "form",
                    open: function (event, ui) {


                        jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
                            url: 'api/AdminConsole/GetListDetailData',
                            datatype: "json",
                            colNames: ['Key', 'Value'],
                            colModel: [
                            { name: 'Key', index: 'Key', width: 200, align: "left", editable: true },
                            { name: 'Value', index: 'Value', width: 200, align: "left", editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                            ],
                            jsonReader: {
                                repeatitems: true,
                                page: function () { return 1; },
                                root: function (obj) { return obj.rows; },
                                records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
                            },

                            pager: "#jqGridPager"


                        });

                        $("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid('navGrid', '#jqGridPager',
                                          {
                                              add: true,
                                              edit: true,
                                              del: true
                                          });






                    },


                });
            });

        });
    });



    $("#jqtable").dialog("open");
```

UI for  dialog displays [like this and content are non editable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rAhU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer

Added below code

$(document).ready(function () {

```
 $.fn.jqm = false;

    $.jgrid.jqModal = $.jgrid.jqModal || {};

    $.extend(true, $.jgrid.jqModal, { toTop: true });

});
```